# How to visit the /data folder on my Android on my PC?

Tags: file-system

For example

> /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts.db

I cannot see it both in Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't directly mount the internal storage.  You need to be rooted to view it on your phone, or you can use `adb pull` from the Android SDK Tools to copy it off the device.

Comment: What if the phone is encrypted?

Comment: @Dante No idea. I would expect adb to be intelligent enough to ask for a password or something. I've never heard anything about encryption in Gingerbread beyond the fact that it exists.